# How to use attribute metadata token in Orion Context Broker notification custom payload (NGSIV2)?

Tags: publish-subscribe, fiware, fiware-orion

NGSIv2 clients can customize HTTP notification messages using a simple template mechanism.

Considering the following notification `notification.httpCustom` object:

```
"httpCustom": {
  "url": "http://foo.com/entity/${id}",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
  },
  "method": "PUT",
  "qs": {
    "type": "${type}"
  },
  "payload": "The temperature is ${temperature} degrees"
}
```

The token `${temperature}` will be parsed by current context value.

Thinking that attribute could have a metadata value could contain custom data like a `temperature.scale`, to store values of '°C' or '°F' for example. How can I print it in that message?

Although attributes metadata there are 2 Special metadata in notifications:

> - `previousValue`. The value of this metadata must be the previous value of the associated attribute. The type of this metadata must be
>     the previous type of the associated attribute. If the type/value of
>     previousValue is the same type/value than in the associated attribute,
>     then the attribute has not actually changed its value.
> - `actionType`. It is included if the attribute to which it is attached was included in the request that triggered the notification.
>     Its value depends on the request operation type: update for updates,
>     append for the creation and delete for deletion. Its type is always Text.

The final result should be a message like that:

> The temperature is now -10 °C degrees before was 9.1 °C degrees

Is it possible, who to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification templating mechanism specified in [NGSIv2 stable version RC-2016.10](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/) (reference NGSIv2 version for current Orion Context Broker version, i.e. 1.7.0) doesn't implement metadata value substitution. It could be implemented in a next version.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho, your question is in fact proposing an interesting functional extension of the custom notification feature :) Could you fill an issue in Orion repository (https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/new) so it could be taken into account for a future version, pls? Once you do it, include the link as a response to this comment. Thanks!